# Set cookie to have a value of form entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

Asked a related question earlier, but it looks like it was lacking a context, so, couldn't make it work.
Trying to set a cookie value of a form entry on click (using carhartl jquery plugin). And getting nothing. Not even errors.
Cookies plugin is included into head portion of the page.

html of it

```
    <input type="text" class="signfield emfield" />
    <input type="text" class="signfield nam1field" />
    <input type="text" class="signfield nam2field" />
    <div class="submt sbmtfrm" style="cursor:pointer;">Step 2</div>
```

and jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(window, $){
    var emailvar;
    var name1var;
    var name2var;
    $(".sbmtfrm").click(function(){
        emailvar = $(".emfield").val();
        name1var = $(".nam1field").val();
        name2var = $(".nam2field").val();
        alert(emailvar);
        $.cookie("sec8email", emailvar);
        $.cookie("sec8name1", name1var);
        $.cookie("sec8name2", name2var);
    });

    var emvar = $.cookie("sec8email");
    var name1 = $.cookie("sec8name1");
    var name2 = $.cookie("sec8name2");

}(window, jQuery));
```

Comment: Can you post the scripts you include?

Comment: Just edited the question. I've simply copied and pasted the plugin code between <script> tags. Initial error was a small typo in the plugin. But now i don't get anything. even error messages

Comment: I included my answer on what I think might be going on. Let me know if you see anything if you try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you pass into `ready` is actually executed before the DOM is ready since you call it. This should call it when the DOM is ready and still maintain what you want to do.

```
(function(window, $){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var emailvar;
        var name1var;
        var name2var;
        $(".sbmtfrm").click(function(){
            emailvar = $(".emfield").val();
            name1var = $(".nam1field").val();
            name2var = $(".nam2field").val();
            alert(emailvar);
            $.cookie("sec8email", emailvar);
            $.cookie("sec8name1", name1var);
            $.cookie("sec8name2", name2var);
        });

        var emvar = $.cookie("sec8email");
        var name1 = $.cookie("sec8name1");
        var name2 = $.cookie("sec8name2");

    });
}(window, jQuery));
```

`function(window,jQuery){...}(window,jQuery)` will execute the function and return `undefined`, so you would be doing `$document.ready(undefined)`